# Finding the probability for specific birthday problem.

Tags: probability

Given that a year is divided into 26 equally long periods (14 days per period) and that there are 8 persons.

1. What are chances that at least 1 out of 8 persons is born in a given period?
2. What are chances that 2 out of 8 persons are born in the same period?
3. How many persons are needed, in order for the chances to be greater than 3/4 that one person is born in period no. 5?
4. How many persons are needed, in order for the chances to be smaller than 1/2 that all persons are born in different periods?

EDIT: Adding thing mentioned in the comment.

1. Well the probability one person is born in a certain period is, of course, 1/26. My idea was that probability for 8 person is just 8 sums, giving 8/26. However the solution is 1-(25/26)^8. Ok, 1 is overall probability, 25/26 is probability a person is not born in the period. I am, however confused with the multiplication. Why multiplication instead of sum?
2. Here I would say the solution is putting the solution of 1. to the power of 2, as in if a probability of one person has been born in a period is 8/26 then the second person has the same probability. The both would give (8/26)^2.

For the 3. and 4. task I have no ideas...

Thanks!

Comment: Hi welcome to SE. Please let us know what you have already tried. It is much easier to help people if we know what you've tried (this also tells us what level to pitch the answer at). It also lets us know that we aren't just doing your homework for you - no one really likes that.

Comment: I added my take on the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Background**

Addition and multiplication are used for special cases in probability.

In one event if there are multiple different mutually exclusive outcomes (can't happen at the same time) then you can add the probabilities to get the total. E.g. What is the probability of rolling a 2 or a 4 on one roll of a dice: $\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6} = \frac{2}{6}$.

In multiple independent events (ones which don't affect each other) if we want to determine the probability of all being successful then we multiple the probabilities of the individual events. E.g. What is the probability of rolling a 2 on one dice roll then rolling a 4 on a second dice roll: $\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{36}$

If we want to determine the probability of something not happening (the complement) then we can do 1 take away the probability of it occuring. E.g. What is the probability of not rolling a six: $1-\frac{1}{6}=\frac{5}{6}$

**Questions**

Each birth is an individual event which we can assume are independent. (We aren't told they are twins or anything like that.) So the probability of a person being in a particular period is $\frac{1}{26}$ and the probability of them not being in a particular period is $\frac{25}{26}$.

1) The probability of one person having their birthday in a period is $\frac{1}{26}$. You need to find the probability of one or more people having their birthday in one section. This could be 1 person, 2 people, etc which would be lots of calculations to do. Instead lets look at the complement (the opposite) of that - what is the probability that no-one has their birthday in that period. This is easier to do as there is only one value to consider: zero people. The probability of the first person not having their birthday in that period is $\frac{25}{26}$. The probability is the same for the other 7 people. The birthdays of these people are independent event (or so we must assume) so the probability of no-one having their birthday in the period is $\left(\frac{25}{26}\right)^8$. Hence the probability of one or more having their birthday in that period is: $$1-\left(\frac{25}{26}\right)^8$$

2) For two people to be born in the same period you need everyone else not to be born in the same period. Plus you need to consider how many ways we can pick two people to have their birthday in that period. This becomes:
$$\left(\frac{1}{26}\right)^2\times\left(\frac{25}{26}\right)^6\times\space^8C_2=\frac{28\times25^6}{26^8}$$

**Note for 3 & 4:** Here we are no longer looking at 8 people. Let the number of people be $n$.

3) This is similar to question 2. We want one person born in the period and $n-1$ not born in the period. So it becomes: 
$$\frac{1}{26}\times\left(\frac{25}{26}\right)^{n-1}\times\space^nC_1>\frac{3}{4}$$
$$\frac{n\times25^{n-1}}{26^n}>\frac{3}{4}$$
This has no solution. Did you mean to ask "that *at least* one person in born in period no. 5"?

4) I've run out of time for now. I'll try to update this later. This problem is related to the [Birthday Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) and that would be good to read up on.